# In Clickhouse is there a way to generate a SHA1 (version 5) UUID based on supplied data?

Tags: sql, uuid, sha1, clickhouse

I am trying to create a custom function in Clickhouse that will generate a SHA1 (version 5) UUID based on a supplied name space and data. Similar to how it is done [here](https://github.com/google/uuid/blob/44b5fee7c49cf3bcdf723f106b36d56ef13ccc88/hash.go#L51). Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you'd use a `FixedString(16)` as the type, concatenate the namespace and name, [hash it](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/hash-functions#sha1-sha224-sha256-sha512) and add the version and variant bits with [bit functions](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/bit-functions).

Comment: Thanks @Schwern! I'm have difficulty with the implementation. Can you help me understand what it might look like?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have ClickHouse. I'm just reading the docs.